# Изменение реестра в пайтоне

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

У меня есть вот такой код который ставит обои на компьютер

```
import ctypes
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14  

SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE   = 0x2 
path = r"D:\Downloads\_wallpapers\3D-graphics_Line_025147_.jpg" 

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE)
```

Но после перезагрузки они сбрасываются.
Как я прочитал это связано с тем, что в реестре это не сохраняется

Можно ли как то изменить реестр через пайтон что бы обои сохранялись?